# Why is manually moving a UIImageView slow?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am trying to write a head-to-head iPhone Air Hockey (like) game. When the user touches the screen I move the "puck" by placing the UIImageView center where the touch center is.

Also I move the puck (another UIImageView) using a timer. This method is slow and shaky. I know I can get performance out of OpenGL ES but I do not want it to get that involved if I can help it.

I would also like to take advantage of the animation engine for special effects and such. How can I manually move the paddles and puck to a timer and get better performance. Or do I just have to embrace OpenGL ES for this?

Comment: What is your timer update rate?  Do the images have transparency?  Have you tried turning on the opaque attribute? I use the same approach (moving UIImageViews) and it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Have you tried drawing the puck (in drawRect) manually rather than using an image? I agree with Mr Bird - the timer period seems key - and any other code you feel able to post.

Comment: How do you set the timer update rate?

Comment: This should be a question. However, you set an interval when you create a timer. Go to http://appsamuck.com/ and look at this example which creates a timer http://appsamuck.com/day31.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or do I just have to embrace the OpenGL?

No there is a middle ground: CoreAnimation.

Matt Gallagher has a [demo game](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/02/asteroids-style-game-in-coreanimation.html) (for Mac) which uses Core Animation to display sprites. You will not see the same performance on iPhone as desktop but, your game is much simpler than his example.